# TypeError: Cannot read property 'expParams' of null

Tags: javascript, typeerror, rpgmakermv

I encountered an error in the RPG MAKER MZ program
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/63gon.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Relevant code and error messages need to be included in your question *as text*, not as pictures of text.  Just linking to screen shots makes it more difficult for people to help you.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Congratulations !

Comment: Can you please show as a part of code where `expParams` is used not as a picture? Because a part of code where is only `console.log` is not informative